# Yahtzee program

Tags: ruby, game, random, playing-cards, dice

How can I refactor this?

```
require'yaml'
require 'text-table'

class Yahtzee
  def initialize
    puts "Welcome to Yahtzee, please enter your name."
    @name = gets.chomp
    @turn = 0
    @scorecard = {"aces" => 0, "twos" => 0, "threes" => 0, "fours" => 0, "fives" => 0, "sixes" => 0, "3 of a kind" => 0, "4 of a kind" => 0, "full house" => 0, "sm. straight" => 0, "lg. straight" => 0, "chance" => 0, "yahtzee" => 0}
end

def roll
@roll_count = 1
    @roll = Array.new(5) {rand(6) + 1}
    p @roll
    puts "That was your first roll, you are allowed 2 more rolls."
    more_rolls?
end

def more_rolls?
    puts "Would you like to roll again? (y or n)"
    roll_again_choice = gets.chomp.downcase
    if roll_again_choice == "y"
        roll_again
    elsif roll_again_choice == "n"
        section(@roll)
    else
      more_rolls?
    end
end
#Refactor for error on input of anything besides 1-5 and commas
def roll_again
    puts "Which dice would you like to keep from this roll? (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"
    dice_to_keep = gets.chomp.split(',').map {|x| (x.to_i) - 1}.map {|x| @roll[x]}
    new_roll = Array.new(5 - dice_to_keep.size) {rand(6) + 1}
    @roll = new_roll + dice_to_keep
    p @roll
    @roll_count += 1
    puts "That was roll number #{@roll_count}, you have #{3-@roll_count} remaining."
    if @roll_count < 3
        more_rolls?
    else
        section(@roll)
    end
end

def section(roll)
    view_scorecard
    puts "\nYou rolled a #{roll}. What section would you like to score?"
    section_choice = gets.chomp.downcase
    section_to_score(section_choice)
end

def section_to_score(section_choice)
    if @scorecard[section_choice] == 0
        case section_choice
            when "aces" then ones
            when "twos" then twos
            when "threes" then threes
            when "fours" then fours
            when "fives" then fives
            when "sixes" then sixes
            when "3 of a kind" then three_of_a_kind
            when "4 of a kind" then four_of_a_kind
            when "full house" then full_house
            when "sm. straight" then sm_straight
            when "lg. straight" then lg_straight
            when "yahtzee" then yahtzee
            when "chance" then @scorecard["chance"] = @roll.inject(:+)
            else
                puts "Please choose a section to score."
                section_choice = gets.chomp.downcase
                section_to_score[section_choice]
        end
    elsif @scorecard["yahtzee"] == 50
        yahtzee_plus
    else
        puts "You already scored that section, please choose another section."
        section_choice = gets.chomp
        @turn -= 1
        section_to_score(section_choice)
    end

    @turn += 1
    if @turn == 13
        @scorecard = @scorecard.each_key {|k| @scorecard[k] == "scratch" ? @scorecard[k] = 0 : @scorecard[k]}
        view_scorecard
        @top_total = @scorecard.values_at("aces", "twos", "threes", "fours", "fives", "sixes").inject(:+)
        @lower_total = @scorecard.values_at("3 of a kind", "4 of a kind", "full house", "sm. straight", "lg. straight", "chance", "yahtzee").inject(:+)
        bonus
        @grand_total = @top_total + @lower_total
        view_scorecard
        highscore
    else
        puts "\nYou have #{13 - @turn} turns left. Roll again."
        view_scorecard
    end
end

def ones
    if @roll.include?(1)
        @scorecard["aces"] = @roll.select {|x| x == 1}.inject(:+)
    else
        @scorecard["aces"] = "scratch"
    end
end

def twos
    if @roll.include?(2)
        @scorecard["twos"] = @roll.select {|x| x == 2}.inject(:+)
    else
        @scorecard["twos"] = "scratch"
    end
end

def threes
    if @roll.include?(3)
        @scorecard["threes"] = @roll.select {|x| x == 3}.inject(:+)
    else
        @scorecard["threes"] = "scratch"
    end
end

def fours
    if @roll.include?(4)
        @scorecard["fours"] = @roll.select {|x| x == 4}.inject(:+)
    else
        @scorecard["fours"] = "scratch"
    end
end

def fives
    if @roll.include?(5)
        @scorecard["fives"] = @roll.select {|x| x == 5}.inject(:+)
    else
        @scorecard["fives"] = "scratch"
    end
end

def sixes
    if @roll.include?(6)
        @scorecard["sixes"] = @roll.select {|x| x == 6}.inject(:+)
    else
        @scorecard["sixes"] = "scratch"
    end
end

def three_of_a_kind
    if @roll.map {|x| @roll.count(x)}.any? {|y| y >= 3}
        @scorecard["3 of a kind"] = @roll.inject(:+)
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a 3 of a kind! Please select another section or type 'scratch' to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["3 of a kind"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            three_of_a_kind
        end
    end
end

def four_of_a_kind
    if @roll.map {|x| @roll.count(x)}.any? {|y| y >= 4}
        @scorecard["4 of a kind"] = @roll.inject(:+)
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a 4 of a kind! Please select another section or type scratch to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["4 of a kind"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            four_of_a_kind
        end
    end
end

def full_house
    if @roll.map {|x| @roll.count(x)}.any? {|y| y == 2} && @roll.map {|z| @roll.count(z)}.any? {|i| i == 3}
        @scorecard["full house"] = 25
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a Full House! Please select another section or type scratch to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["full house"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            full_house
        end
    end
end

def has_straight?(need)
num = 1
@roll = @roll.sort.uniq

@roll.each_with_index do |e, i|
    if i < @roll.length-1 then
    if (@roll[i+1] - @roll[i]) > 1 then
        break if num >= need
        num = 1
    end

    num += 1
    end
end

num >= need
end

def sm_straight
    if has_straight?(4)
        @scorecard["sm. straight"] = 30
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a sm. straight! Please select another section or type scratch to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["sm. straight"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            sm_straight
        end
    end
end

def lg_straight
    if has_straight?(5)
        @scorecard["lg. straight"] = 40
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a lg. straight! Please select another section or type scratch to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["lg. straight"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            lg_straight
        end
    end
end

def yahtzee
    if @roll.uniq.size == 1
        @scorecard["yahtzee"] = 50
    else
        puts "Your roll is not a Yahtzee! Please select another section or type scratch to score 0 for this section."
        scratch = gets.chomp
        if scratch == "scratch"
            @scorecard["yahtzee"] = "scratch"
        elsif @scorecard.has_key?(scratch)
            @turn -= 1
            section_to_score(scratch)
        else
            yahtzee
        end
    end
end

def yahtzee_plus
    if @roll.uniq.size == 1
        puts "You scored another Yahtzee! Please choose what section you want to score your 100 points!"
        yahtzee_placement = gets.chomp
        @scorecard[yahtzee_placement] = 100
    else
        "Your roll is not a Yahtzee! Please select another section."
        section_choice = gets.chomp
        @turn -= 1
        section_to_score(section_choice)
    end
end

def view_scorecard
    table = Text::Table.new :rows => [["YAHTZEE",{:value => "Scorecard", :align => :center},"NAME:#{@name}"],:separator,
    ['Upper Section', 'How to Score', 'Score'],
    :separator,
    ['Aces', 'Count & Add Only Aces', {:value => "#{@scorecard["aces"]}", :align => :right}], 
    ['Twos', 'Count & Add Only Twos', {:value => "#{@scorecard["twos"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['Threes', 'Count & Add Only Threes', {:value => "#{@scorecard["threes"]}", :align => :right}], 
    ['Fours', 'Count & Add Only Fours', {:value => "#{@scorecard["fours"]}", :align => :right}], 
    ['Fives', 'Count & Add Only Fives', {:value => "#{@scorecard["fives"]}", :align => :right}], 
    ['Sixes', 'Count & Add Only Sixes', {:value => "#{@scorecard["sixes"]}", :align => :right}],
    :separator,
    ['Bonus', 'Score 35', {:value => "#{@bonus}", :align => :right}], 
    :separator,
    ['Upper Total', '--------------------->', {:value => "#{@top_total}", :align => :right}], 
    :separator,
    ['Lower Section', 'How to Score', 'Score'], 
    :separator,
    ['3 of a Kind', 'Add Total of All Dice', {:value => "#{@scorecard["3 of a kind"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['4 of a Kind', 'Add Total of All Dice', {:value => "#{@scorecard["4 of a kind"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['Full House', 'Score 25', {:value => "#{@scorecard["full house"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['Sm. Straight', 'Score 30', {:value => "#{@scorecard["sm. straight"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['Lg. Straight', 'Score 40', {:value => "#{@scorecard["lg. straight"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['Yahtzee', 'Score 50', {:value => "#{@scorecard["yahtzee"]}", :align => :right}],
    ['Chance', 'Add Total of All Dice', {:value => "#{@scorecard["chance"]}", :align => :right}],
    :separator,
    ['Lower Total', '--------------------->', {:value => "#{@lower_total}", :align => :right}],
    :separator,
    ['Upper Total', '--------------------->', {:value => "#{@top_total}", :align => :right}],
    :separator,
    ['Grand Total', '--------------------->', {:value => "#{@grand_total}", :align => :right}]]

    puts table
end

def bonus
    if @top_total >= 63
        @top_total += 35
        @bonus = 35
        p "You received a 35 point bonus for having at least 63 points in the top section!"  
    else
        @top_total
        @bonus = 0
    end
end

def highscore
if File.exists?('highscore.txt')
    hs = YAML.load_file("highscore.txt")
else
    hs = {
        1 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        2 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        3 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        4 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        5 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        6 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        7 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        8 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        9 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        10 => { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        }
end

(1..10).each do |rank|
  t = Time.now
  if @grand_total > hs[rank][:score]
    hs[rank][:score] = @grand_total
    hs[rank][:date] = "#{t.month}/#{t.day}/#{t.year}"
    hs[rank][:player] = @name
    puts "Congratulations you set a new HIGH SCORE!"
    break
  end
end

puts "Thanks for playing!"

File.write('highscore.txt', hs.to_yaml)
hs_table = YAML.load_file('highscore.txt')

hs_table_rank = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"]

hs_table_players = (1..10).map do |rank|
hs_table[rank][:player]
end

hs_table_scores = (1..10).map do |rank|
hs_table[rank][:score]
end

hs_table_dates = (1..10).map do |rank|
hs_table[rank][:date]
end

hs_table = hs_table_rank, hs_table_players, hs_table_scores, hs_table_dates
hs_table = hs_table.transpose

hs_table.unshift(["RANK", "PLAYER", "SCORE", "DATE"])
puts hs_table.to_table(:first_row_is_head => true)
end

end
```

Comment: It's a lot of code, but a Ruby guy (not me) might find some improvements/best practices. Why the close vote?

Comment: @mnhg Questions containing just code with no explanation tend to be closed, because it's not clear what is the OP asking for. But I think that in this case, the title of the question is enough.

Comment: According to the title and the context he ask for general improvements. Stating this in the post would be nice, but doing it not seem no reason for closing this post.

Comment: I was told by someone at StackOverflow that after I wrote code I was satisfied with, in this case the program executing start to finish correctly after several games, that I should put it on codereview so that more experienced programmers can refactor it and show me Ruby best practices. I am new to Ruby and programming in general, this is my first full program, I did not mean to post incorrectly if that is the case.

Comment: For starters you might want to consider switching to two-space indent, which is a very strong convention in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with code formatting :D And replacing `@scorecard` initialization with following one (instead of explicit zerofication):

```
@scorecard = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0 }
```

In nearly all cases you use `gets`, you puts before:

```
puts "Your roll is not a Full House!.."
scratch = gets.chomp
```

You can extract this into a dedicated method:

```
def ask message
  puts message
  gets.chomp
end
```

So that your calls will become:

```
scratch = ask "Your roll is not a Full House!.."
```

This place seems useless:

```
File.write('highscore.txt', hs.to_yaml)
hs_table = YAML.load_file('highscore.txt')
```

Final multiple `map`s can be replaced into something more beautiful, but we will need something to make ordinal numbers, we'll steel this method from ActiveSupport (Ruby on Rails):

```
def ordinalize(number)
  abs_number = number.to_i.abs

  if (11..13).include?(abs_number % 100)
    suffix = "th"
  else
    suffix = case abs_number % 10
      when 1; "st"
      when 2; "nd"
      when 3; "rd"
      else    "th"
    end
  end

  "#{number}#{suffix}"
end
```

Once we have this, we can refactor last maps into something like this:

```
hs_table = [["RANK", "PLAYER", "SCORE", "DATE"]]
(1..10).each do |rank|
  hs_table << [
    ordinalize(rank),
    hs_table[rank][:player],
    hs_table[rank][:score],
    hs_table[rank][:date]
  ]
end
```

Well at least these are first steps I would take. After first iteration, there might be more ideas more.